# typescript: Better way to type optional without default value?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am writing react application with typescript.
To provide a typed props I am using the code below.

```js
type ScheduleBoxContentProps = {
  desc: ReactNode,
  lottie: LottieProps,
} & Partial<{className: string}>;
```

As you can see, I want `className` prop to be optional, but don't want to define `defaultProps` for it. In addition, `desc` and `lottie` props should be provided.

Is there any better way to define **optional without default** ?

## Edit

I am sorry for the missing context.

If I use `React.FC` with my custom prop type then there is no problem. Because `React.FC` uses `Partial` inside of it.

```js
type MyProps = {
  className?: string;
}
// no erros and warnings
const Component: React.FC<MyProps> = (props) => <div />;
```

But I don't want my component to accept the `children` props. I want my component to alert when `children` props are coming. Thus I am using function components with code below.

```js
// error: default value for className is not provided. 
const Component = ({className}: MyProps) => <div className={className} />;
```

and it tells me that `className`'s default value are defined. I should define it explicitly. Using code below.

```js
Component.defaultProps = {className: ''};
```

IMO, it seems little bit unnecessary code, so I decided to use `Partial` on optional props.

```js
type MyProps = Partial<{className: string}>;
```

Is there any better way to achieve this? Or, using `defaultProps` is the best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add `?` after the property name:

```js
type ScheduleBoxContentProps = {
  desc: ReactNode,
  lottie: LottieProps,
  
  // This ? is literally what Partial does
  className?: string,
};
```

As for your edited example, what I think would be the most simple is to set the default value in the destructuring syntax:

```js
const Component = ({className = ''}: MyProps) => <div className={className} />;
```

Comment: Sorry for missing context. I added some more information about my situation.

Comment: I edited my response with a possible solution

Comment: I was thinking too complicated. You point me out the right solution with a basic :) Thanks a lot!. I would use your solution for simple props and `Partial` for other complicated props if it happens.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
className?: string;
```

Comment: Sorry for missing context. I added some more information about my situation.